# yocto 32 bit packages using multilib

Tags: yocto

I want to use multilib feature in yocto to build some applications in a packagegroup recipe as only 32 bit. Meaning only 32 bit packages which are part of this packagegroup should be placed in image.

i can use bitbake lib32-packagegroup-name.bb to create 32 bit packages from this packagegroup, but the packages in this packagegroup are still building as 64 bit when i am trying to build image

bitbake core-sato-image.bb

Please let me know the changes required ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

multilib-example.conf (from [Github - OpenEmbedded](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta-skeleton/conf/multilib-example.conf)):

```
#
# Sample multilib configuration which the user can either add in local.conf
# or specific in an configuration file like this, then require it.
#
# This configuration specifies an x86 64 bit machine as the main machine
# type and then adds a multilib in the "lib32" directory where those
# libraries are compiled with the "x86" tune.
#

MACHINE = "qemux86-64"
require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"
```

You also need to activate support for 32-bit in the Kernel configuration.
Xilinx has also an example for creating a mulitlib image, which I consider a nice reference: http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Creating+a+multilib+image+for+the+ZCU102+using+Yocto